# Next & Back Buttons for Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, html

How to make the back and next buttons on the 2nd tab work? (Back button goes to Tab 1 & Next button goes to Tab 3). Below is my code.. I know this question has been asked and answered before, but I am not very familiar with jQuery and just copied the code from http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery#step-jquery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
 
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#CCCCCC;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#CCCCCC;
    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
    </ul>
 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
          <a href="#back_tab1"><input type="button" value="Back" id="recipBackButton"></a>
    <a href="#next_tab3"><input type="button" value="Next" id="recipNextButton"></a><br>
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 jQuery('#recipNextButton').on('click', function() {

   var $activeTab = $('.tab-links li.active');
   var $wrapper = jQuery(this).closest('.tabs');
   var indexActive = $wrapper.find('li.active').index();

   $wrapper.find('li').eq(indexActive + 1).find('a').click();
});

jQuery('#recipBackButton').on('click', function() {

   var $activeTab = $('.tab-links li.active');
   var $wrapper = jQuery(this).closest('.tabs');
   var indexActive = $wrapper.find('li.active').index();

   $wrapper.find('li').eq(indexActive - 1).find('a').click();
});
```

Please check it here: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/R5PXH/474/